# How i convert email receiving date to date and time

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

Email receiving date is

**2022-01-22 10:01:02**

Date extract from email header it show:

**2022-01-22 03:01:02-06:00**

I need help to convert email header date **2022-01-22 03:01:02-06:00** to `datetime.datetime(2022, 01, 22, 10, 01, 02, tzinfo=<UTC>)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`datetime.datetime.fromisoformat()` works, so no need to define your own `.strptime`. Just do the timezone conversion after the datetime object is created:

```
import datetime

s = "2022-01-22 03:01:02-06:00"

dt = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(s).astimezone(datetime.timezone.utc)
print(dt)
```